# Incorrect MAC address in switch MAC table

Tags: mac-address, huawei

I'm trying to do up a wiring diagram for a VMWare cluster in a remote data center.  I typically will check the MAC addresses in VMWare VSphere client (`vmnic[x]`) and/or use `esxcli` to do so from SSH on the ESXi hosts.

I'll then log into the switch and look at the MAC table to see what port a MAC address was learned from and go from there.

Having an odd issue with Huawei CloudEngine 6800 series switches where the MAC address that's reported in the MAC table (`display mac-addresses | include xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`) is off on the last bit.

For example, vmnic0 is one port on a Broadcom QLogic 57800 2x10GbE + 2x1GbE quad adapter, which reports as `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b5`.  Filtering on `xxxx-xxxx-xxb5` produced zero results in the filtering options.  However, there's an entry for `xxxx-xxxx-xxb6`.

I checked a few more NICs and it appears that it's just the Broadcom QLogic 57800 (and 57810) ones are the only ones with inconsistencies, both 10GbE and 1GbE: it's as if the MACs are all off by a bit (`c0` shows up as `c1` on the switch, `c2` as `c3` and so on).

Now I'm a bit rusty, but I know that converged interfaces can be "sliced up" into sub-interfaces, which would have different MAC addresses, but that would also be represented higher up in the "stack" in ESXi, so presumably the source MAC is being parsed out of the frame correctly.

Just not sure if this is a "UX" problem (the `display mac-addresses` command/switch has bugs) or potentially a driver/incompatibility issue or I'm missing something here.

### Command Outputs:

`vmnic02` is the only MAC address that's reporting "correctly".  I guess you can assume that `b5` is what the Huawei thinks is `b6` and `b7` is what the Huawei thinks is `b8`, but I have no explanation as to why.

Card is this from what I can tell, going by the PCI slots (quad card, not dual)
http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=ie&l=en&s=dhs&cs=iedhs1&sku=540-bbfh#Overview

```
Name    PCI Device    Driver  Admin Status  Link Status  Speed  Duplex  MAC Address         MTU  Description
------  ------------  ------  ------------  -----------  -----  ------  -----------------  ----  -------------------------------------------------------------
vmnic0  0000:01:00.0  bnx2x   Up            Up           10000  Full    11:22:33:44:55:b5  1500  Broadcom Corporation QLogic 57800 10 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
vmnic1  0000:01:00.1  bnx2x   Up            Up           10000  Full    11:22:33:44:55:b7  1500  Broadcom Corporation QLogic 57800 10 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
vmnic2  0000:01:00.2  bnx2x   Up            Up            1000  Full    11:22:33:44:55:b9 1500  Broadcom Corporation QLogic 57800 1 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
vmnic3  0000:01:00.3  bnx2x   Up            Up            1000  Full    11:22:33:44:55:bb  1500  Broadcom Corporation QLogic 57800 1 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
vmnic4  0000:83:00.0  bnx2x   Up            Up           10000  Full    aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:20  1500  Broadcom Corporation QLogic 57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
vmnic5  0000:83:00.1  bnx2x   Up            Up           10000  Full    aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:22  1500  Broadcom Corporation QLogic 57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter


display mac-address | include 1122-3344-55
---- Flags: * - Backup
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MAC Address    VLAN/VSI                          Learned-From        Type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1122-3344-55b6 15/-                               10GE1/0/1           dynamic
1122-3344-55b8 16/-                               10GE2/0/1           dynamic
1122-3344-55b9 19/-                               10GE2/0/9           dynamic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT 2017/06/28:

Checked iDRAC on host, two 10GbE ports are configured in Standard Mode and iSCSI is not enabled on the adapters nor in ESXi (portgroup has iSCSI Bindings disabled) so I don't think is a case of a "leaking" iSCSI frame: if it was, you'd likely see an *extra* MAC address, not an incorrect one as the total MAC count, despite being off incrementally, is still correct.

One thing I noticed is that ESXi vSphere Win32 client sees it as two dual adapters under host > Configuration > Network Adapters.

Checked driver, seems ok, so still thinking this is a Huawei issue.  Think next step is to do a packet capture and/or call Huawei support.

Comment: Have you double-checked with the MAC addresses the other switches show for the Huawei switch links? If these are as expected there must be a problem with the display function.

Comment: I wonder if you're expecting the wrong MAC address value.  In your example, xx:b5 and xx:b6 aren't off by one bit, they're off by two.   5 is 0x101 and 6 is 0x110.  The last two bits have to change. So that would imply something other than a bad bit.  I don't think anything is wrong with the switch.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host, server, or VM configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: @RonMaupin this is purely a network question; obviously any switch in production is going to have hosts on it, so there's going to be some inevitable overlap.

Comment: @RonTrunk see edit re: MAC addresses and display output.

Comment: The community has decided that questions about host, server, or VM configurations are off-topic here. Those type of questions can be asked on [sf] for business network, or on [su] for personal networks. See [meta], specifically: https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/405/8499 and https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/244/8499.

Comment: @gravyface  It's hard to imagine how the switch could be reporting the MAC addresses incorrectly by adding 1 (not one 'bit') *only* for a particular NIC card.  That just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @RonTrunk I'm with you broseph, but you've seen the command outputs; and it's actually two cards that are incorrect (same host) Broadcom QLogic 57800 daughter card (4-ports) and the 57810 on-board dual.

Comment: @RonTrunk but like I said: I see the same MAC addresses across three different visual representations on the host itself: iDRAC > Hardware > Network Devices, esxcli, and vSphere client.  I'm leaning towards a parsing error in the Huawei "display mac-addresses" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rereading your question, I'm pretty sure what the cause is: it's a dual NIC and you just mentioned a single MAC. Dual or quad NICs often (always?) have consecutive MAC addresses(*) and xxxb6 is just the 2nd port.

Depending on your vSwitch NIC teaming/load-balancing setup, the first port may not be in use - so it's invisible in the upstream switch. Open the vSwitch and check the Management Network NIC settings: it shows the MAC the host's network connection uses. On our hosts, it's that of the first NIC listed in vSwitch -> NIC Teaming.

If you do want to always use the first ports MAC you can set specific Management Network teaming with the second port only as fallback. Both ports active will arrange a somewhat random binding of Management Network to physical port.

(*) Our quad NICs with iSCSI option use every other MAC for normal Ethernet.

Comment: But if the port isn't in-use, then the switch wouldn't have learned it's MAC address as it hasn't received a frame yet.  Regardless, it still doesn't explain why it's learned MAC addresses that I cannot account for on the ESXi host and why they're off by 2: I did a partial filter on xxxx-xxxx and none of those MACs match what ESXi is reporting (via GUI or esxcli), but yet they're so close, they have to be the same interfaces.

Comment: If it isn't in use the switch can't learn the MAC, 100% correct. Define "isn't in use": it's unconnected? Configured as fall-back only? Possibly it's just a mix up of ports - the first port may just have the higher MAC and the 2nd the lower. Alternatively, the port order varies between figures on the slot and enumeration in the driver.

Comment: see my edit above for command outputs.

Comment: According to [the datasheet](http://www.qlogic.com/OEMPartnerships/Dell/Documents/Converged/DataSheet_57800SDell_CNDC_QuadPort_10GBASE-T.pdf), the card's got an iSCSI initiator - MACs alternate between plain Ethernet and iSCSI. Even if plain Ethernet isn't used the iSCSI part may be leaking out a frame or two.

Comment: interesting, I'll have to dig a bit further into the vmnic usage; may be that the "correct" MAC on the quad card is the only active Ethernet interface in an active/active pair on the vSwitch.

Comment: see latest edit, but iDRAC confirms the MAC addresses are correct on the hardware: outside of pulling the cards and checking the sticker, I think it's either the Huawei or a bad driver (see edit).

Comment: Have you checked on the further upstream switches (or just connected one)? Whether they display the MAC from iDRAC or the Huawei one?

Comment: I think it's FCoE spamming in the vmkernel.log; there's a few VMware community posts on that and I certainly see it in the vmkernel.log, like constantly.  I don't know alot about FCoE (reading now), but I would suspect that the incremental MAC addresses would belong to FCoE frames.  This actually makes sense and why I'm not seeing the "real" MAC: the quad ports in question aren't vmkernel interfaces, but merely uplinks for the vSwitch, so their own MACs would never really be "learned"; maybe on boot-up or something, but certainly not for forwarding reasons.

Comment: Very likely. As long as the FCoE (or iSCSI for that matter) initiator isn't completely shut off, it may send discovery frames or such, so the switch picks up the MAC.

Comment: There's a command to disable that I'm going to try.  Thanks for (in)directly leading me to what I'm 99% certain is the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

(Would prefer to comment but not enough reputation...)

If I was troubleshooting this on my network, first thing I'd do is run a packet capture from the vmware side. This will confirm what MAC is being sent to the Broadcom switches.  https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc%2FGUID-1BFB05E3-7171-464C-9603-8781C5A97CC6.html

You might also try plugging the same port into a different switch to see if the MAC changes.

I'd also be curious to view upstream switches to see what MAC the Broadcom switches are passing on (presumably the same +1 MAC, right?).

My intuition says that the vmnic is passing on the +1 mac (Cisco devices increment their MACs for each interface, maybe something similar for vmware?) or there's *ahem* human error involved at some point.

Comment: can't plug in anything; remote data centre.  +1 to sniffing, but not sure if ESXi supports tcpdump; was next on the Google hit list, however.

Comment: thanks for this too.  Didn't tell me what I needed, but super handy nonetheless (but apparently I can't upvote this).

Answer (score 0):

It's your filter that's wrong. Syntax for mac addresses varies.  Sometimes its ff:ff:ff: ... and sometimes it's ffff.ffff ..., etc.  Double check your syntax.

Comment: It depends on the device. On example, Cisco displays MAC's as xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, HP SOHO - xxxxxx-xxxxxx, HP A/E - xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, Juniper - xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Comment: Huawei uses a dashed notation (xxxx-xxxx-xxxx), ESXi uses a semi-colon notation (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx); double-checked many (many) times, not a filter/formatting issue.

Comment: well heck, that was my 2 cents. ...BTW 'x' is not a valid hex value :-)